# problem with size of debug.log file

Tags: debug

my debug.log file in wp-content size in above 4GB and have trouble with that.
can I delete this file from the server? 
if delete debug.log file ، No problem with my site? Does everything correctly run in the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debug.log is exactly what it sounds - it’s just a file that contains log information for debugging purposes.

You can easily delete it and without any fear.

But...

1. Debugging should not be turned on on production site - it’s a security problem.
2. If your debug.log file is so big, then your site has many problems. This file contains PHP notices, warnings and errors. If everything works fine, then this file is almost empty.

So the smart thing to do is:

- download that file to your local machine,
- delete it from server
- check the content of that file and try to fix as much problems as you can
- disable logging or at least make that file inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove the log, it will not affect to the website.

If you want to get log content without manipulating the file in File Managers or by FTP - try the [Issues Tracker](https://wordpress.org/plugins/issues-tracker/) plugin.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/266005)